# How to expand the width of the backdrop-filter?

Tags: html, css

I have a question. I am wondering how am I able to expand the width of my backdrop-filter for the entire right side of the screen and also some of the left side as well. I tried to see if padding was the solution but that didn't give me the results I want. It helps me for increasing the height but doesn't give me the right results for the width. The first photo shows what I have so far and the second shows what I want it to look like.
[image]

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellefair&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Space tourism website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="top-logo">
    <img class="logo" src="assets/shared/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">00</span>Home</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">01</span>Destination</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">02</span>Crew</a>
    <a href="#"><span class="nav-number">03</span>Technology</a>
  </div>
  <div class="description-container">
    <h5>So, you want to travel to</h5>
    <h1>Space</h1>
    <p>Let’s face it; if you want to go to space, you might as well genuinely go to
    outer space and not hover kind of on the edge of it. Well sit back, and relax
    because we’ll give you a truly out of this world experience!</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Explore</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  background-image: url('../assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
hr {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 9.375rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 6.25rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 4.75px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
p {
  width: 32%;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #D0D6F9;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 70px;
}
.top-logo {
  margin: 53px 0 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > a {
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.nav-number {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  right: 230px;
  background: hsl(0 0% 100% / 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
}
.description-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 150px;
  width:250px;
height:250px;
border-radius: 50%;
border:none;
background-color:white;
font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:hover {
  outline:50px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're using a lot of absolute positioning here which looks like it's causing quite a few issues.

Nevertheless, you could achieve what you're trying to by changing `.nav` with something like

```css
.nav {
  padding: 24px 100px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Are using all of these absolute positions bad?